# FB.ui apprequest, get selected user IDs

Tags: facebook

How can I retrieve the user IDs that were checked in the multi-friend-selector generated by the Application Request Dialog? Ive tried :

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
        message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.request_ids) {
            console.log(response.request_ids);
        } 
    });
```

But I dont get any results in the console. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code.

```
FB.ui({ 
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...' 
}, function(res){
  if (!res || !res.request_ids) { /* user canceled */ return; }
  var req_ids = res.request_ids;
  var _batch = [];
  for(var i=0; i<req_ids.length; i++ ){
    _batch.push({"method":"get","relative_url":req_ids[i]});
  }
  if(_batch.length>0){
    FB.api('/','POST',{batch:_batch},function(res){
      //res contains uids.
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: res.request_ids doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 3):

here is an article on how to get request objects in PHP and how to get information out of the request object. http://denverapps.co/list-of-user-ids-from-requests-dialog-migrating-from-fb-request-form-to-fb-ui-apprequests-facebook-api-javascript-php

Answer (score 2):

request_ids does not exist anymore, just wanted to post the latest code

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "my app request message",
    picture: 'url to my image',
    max_recipients: 'number of recipients in integer (max 50, 30 for IE6/7)'
}, function(response) {
    if(response && response.hasOwnProperty('to')) {
        for(i = 0; i < response.to.length; i++) {
            console.log("" + i + " ID: " + response.to[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the app I am working on right now this

```
response.request_ids
```

doesn't exist anymore.
It seems to now use

```
response.to
```

which is providing me with user ids, not request ids.  The request ids are nowhere to be found but that's ok with me because I want the user ids :)

Here's what my response object looks like in the inspector

```
Object
    request: 12345678909876
    to: Array[2]
    __proto__: Object
```

**Update:**
I just found this in the Facebook API Documentation.  It illustrates what I said above.
It turns out that there is a Requests 2.0 API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/
under the headline `Updated Request ID Format`

Comment: thanks     FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: "Test",
        data: "whatever",
        exclude_ids: excludeids
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.to) {
     for (var j = 0; j < response.to.length; j++) {
      alert(response.to[j]);
     }
  }
 });

Answer (score 1):

heres the new response.to code thanks to pferdefleisch

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: "Test",
    data: "whatever"
}, function (response) {
    if (response && response.to) {
        for (var j = 0; j < response.to.length; j++) {
            alert(response.to[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code ..... 
first of all "response.request_ids" gives you the Request ids not the user ids
FB.api('/me/apprequests/?request_ids=' gives you the data associated with request_ids..
But in my case the problem is that i'm getting a random User id of a friend whom I didn't even select

```
 FB.ui({
     method: 'apprequests',
     message: 'You should learn more about this awesome game.', data: 'tracking information for the user'
   },function(response) {
    if (response && response.request_ids) {
       //alert(typeof(response.request_ids));
       //alert(response.request_ids);
       alert (response.request_ids);
       len=response.request_ids.length;
       alert(len);
        if (len>2) {
               alert("Select no more than one friend");
        }
        else {
             user_req_id = response.request_ids[0];
             alert (user_req_id);
             FB.api('/me/apprequests/?request_ids='+toString(user_req_id),
                function(response) { 
                    alert(response);
                    alert(response['data'][0]['from']['id']); 
                });
                }
        } 
    else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   });
```